# Unzipping images to NSArray ios

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, unzip

I have a zip file of images on my backend server. I want to download the zip and unarchive the content (images) to NSArray. Is there a way to do it?
Thank you)

Comment: Just posting you requirments on Stackoverflow is really frowned up, please post any examples where you have tried to implement the requirement yourself.

Comment: Hi, I never found an example of unarchiving to NSArray, so I am asking if there is even a possibility of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to use [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) in order to work with zip files.

Below line would unzip and assign images to a NSArray

```
   // Unzipping
NSString *zipPath = @"path_to_your_zip_file";
NSString *destinationPath = @"path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_it_unzipped";
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];

// Zipping
NSString *zippedPath = @"path_where_you_want_the_file_created";
NSArray *inputPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo1" ofType:@"jpg"],
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo2" ofType:@"jpg"]
                       nil];
[SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zippedPath withFilesAtPaths:inputPaths];
```

To delete a file:

```
- (void)deleteFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
  NSError *error;
  BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
  if (success) {
      UIAlertView *removeSuccessFulAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [removeSuccessFulAlert show];
  }
  else
  {
      NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is cool. How do i delete the zip file and files that I have unzipped, after I put them to NSArray? Thank you. (I ll accept answer in 10 min)

Comment: @sermillion, see how to delete a file programmatically.

Comment: @sermilion, you are welcome, I hope it would be useful for you.